# Displaying Image with Tkinter Using Label Widget

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to display an image using PIL in a Tkinter class:

```
class PasswordCheck(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
            Frame.__init__(self,master)
            self.pack()

    def create_widgets(self):
            self.title=Label(self,text='Curretly using password')
            self.pwfield=Entry(self,text=self.password)
            self.web=Label(self,image=self.image)
            self.ok=Button(self)
            self.ok['text']='OK'
            self.ok['command']=root.destroy
            self.ok.pack(side='top')
            self.quit=Button(self,text="Quit",command=root.destroy)
            self.quit.pack(side='bottom')

    def setParms(self,password,image):
            self.password=password
            self.image=image
```

I need to mention that I am a Tkinter beginner. I create the image from a web site (using HTMLParser) and set up the window thus:

```
with open(authFile,'r') as f:
    lines=f.read().splitlines()
password=lines[1]
f=urllib.urlopen(URL)
parser=PWParser()
parser.feed(f.read())
response=requests.get(URL+imageURL.replace(" ","%20"))
img=PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
root=Tk()
window=PasswordCheck(master=root)
window.setParms(password,img.convert('1').tobitmap())
window.create_widgets()
window.mainloop()
```

The image is good (img.show()) so I converted it to bitmap and passed it to the Tkinter class. When I run the script I get an error saying static char image_bits[] = { ... does not exist:

(cannot post traceback, form incorrectly thinks it is improperly formatted code, need help here)

I read in several places about garbage collection getting rid of the image before it is displayed but it was not clear how to stop that. If that is the reason, how do I keep 'img' from being removed or is there something else wrong? TIA.

Comment: Try saving the result of img.convert('1').tobitmap() to a new variable and use this variable as input to setParms()

Comment: Thanks but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It turns out the image needs to be a photoimage. This is what worked:

```
window.setParms(password,PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="program_logo.gif")

explanation = """At present, only GIF and PPM/PGM
formats are supported, but an interface 
exists to allow additional image file
formats to be added easily."""

w = tk.Label(root, 
             compound = tk.CENTER,
             text=explanation, 
             image=logo).pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

program_logo.gif is your logo but as a .gif file.

I got it from this site: https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php

hope it helps, bye :)